# Case Class constructor parameter give as tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, shapeless, case-class

My model looks something like this:

```
abstract class A(id:String, val time:Int) extends Ordered[A]{
    override def compare(that:TrackingEvent) = this.time.compare(that.time)
}

case class B(id:String, override val time: Int, x:Int, y:int) extends A(id,time) {
    //some methods
}
// more Case Classes who inherit from A
```

I get some Data from a mongodb and store them in some case-classes (every class inherits from A)

What I do at the moment is this:

```
val header = getHeader(doc) //doc => actual row, return: Tuple2(String,Int)
val xy = getXYDatapoint(doc) // return: Tuple2(Int,Int)
val b = B(header._1,header._2,xy._1,xy._2)
```

Every inherited case class uses the same getHeader(doc) function to get the header. (That's why the abstract class A has the two arguments)

I want that it looks nicer so that I can kill some lines.

Something like:

```
val b = B(header+xy)
```

Or something else. I can change the whole Scala code and would open for any help to let it look nicer (I'm new in Scala)

I tried with shapeless but that didn't work:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

val header = getHeader(doc)
val xy = getXY(doc)
val param = header++xy

val b = (B.apply _).tupled(param) // didn't work because param is of type prepend.Out
val b = (B.apply _).tupled(("a",2,3,4)) // would work
```

When someone know some nice tips or tricks I would glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close; you just need to explicitly say that your intended type is a tuple. Here’s a general example for all those in need:

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

case class Test(a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: Int)

val tuple: (Int, Int, String, Int) = (1, 2) ++ ("a", 3)

Test.tupled(tuple) // works
```

However, if I may add, your use case could be simplified by some extra modelling. Then you would not need shapeless at all. Lately I’ve been seeing a lot of people misusing the case classes. They are intended as abstract data types (ADT), not classes in generals sense. If your case class needs to contain some logic, then it’s probably better to make it just a class.

You do have a use case for case classes, though. Why not capture the information about header and data point in two separate ADTs?

Here’s the full code:

```
case class Header(id: String, time: Int)
case class DataPoint(x: Int, y: Int)

abstract class A(id: String, val time: Int) {
  // whatever
}

class B(header: Header, dataPoint: DataPoint) extends A(header.id, header.time) {
  // whatever
}

val dataPoint = DataPoint(1, 2)
val header = Header("header", 42)

val b = new B(header, dataPoint)
```

Of course, if the semantics of class `A`'s parameters `id` and `time` are of those from the header, you could even make `A` take just one parameter: `abstract class A(header: Header)`.

Personally, I think this is clean, clear and well-modelled. Of course, your opinion may be different. :)

Comment: I think your second point is really interesting. But what is when you have a class C which takes an array, class D which takes 2 Strings, .... would you still do the same?

Comment: It always depends on the use case. Do you have C, D etc., each with different data types but all representing header, or are they a bunch of `id`s and `time`s coming from different stuff (not just headers)? BTW let's not over-extend the discussion here :) we resolved the main problem (case class <-> tuple). I gave you a hint regarding design, but for further questions about it we can always meet on gitter or somewhere, or you can post a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

You could define another apply method for the case class:

```scala
case class B(id: String, override val time: Int, x: Int, y: Int) extends A(id, time)
object B {
  def apply(header: (String, Int), coordinates: (Int, Int)): B =
    B(header._1, header._2, coordinates._1, coordinates._2)
}
```

Now you can use it as:

```scala
val header = getHeader(doc)
val coords = getXY(doc)
val b = B(header, coords)
```

This is nice because you don't need to call `tupled` anymore, you just build your instances using the new apply method and pass directly the results of `getHeader` and `getXY`.